# Why do I get an error when I use DumpMachine in q#?

Tags: q#

Here is my code:

```
using (q = Qubit()) {
            Message("Input:");
            Message("q = ∣0❭, index = 1");

            Message("Requaired Output:");
            Message("∣0❭:     0.707107 +  0.000000 i");
            Message("∣1❭:     0.000000 + -0.707107 i");

            Task12(q, 1);
            Message("Your Output:");
            DumpMachine();

            Reset(q);
        }
```

But I get this error:

```
The type or namespace name '_2e502c3cdee5457783e1ea9b1f54eb1b_DumpMachine' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.Quantum.Diagnostics' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
```

Does anyone have an idea why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you verify if you have `open Microsoft.Quantum.Diagnostics;` listed?

I copied your code and added the functions, it works for me, I use .NET Core 3.1 & VisualStudio 2019, here is my code, I also added it to GitHub https://github.com/nahidf-adventures/qsharp-adventures/tree/master/src/QbitSample:

```
namespace QbitSample {

    open Microsoft.Quantum.Canon;
    open Microsoft.Quantum.Intrinsic;
    open Microsoft.Quantum.Measurement;
    open Microsoft.Quantum.Diagnostics;


    @EntryPoint()
    operation HelloQ() : Unit {
        using (q = Qubit()) {
            Message("Input:");
            Message("q = ∣0❭, index = 1");

            Message("Requaired Output:");
            Message("∣0❭:     0.707107 +  0.000000 i");
            Message("∣1❭:     0.000000 + -0.707107 i");

            Task12(q, 1);
            Message("Your Output:");
            DumpMachine();

            Reset(q);
        }
    }

    operation Task12(q: Qubit, count : Int) : Unit {
        }
    }
```

Comment: I followed your footsteps and I created a new project and copied my code, it works now but I don't know why it didn't. Thanks.